# css flex grid with variable heights

Tags: css, flexbox

I am currently learning Flex and have a layout request that I am struggling with. I have a load of images which are currently presented on the page in a UL (although they don't have to be). The required layout is demonstrated below.

***Desktop***

```
+------------+------+
|            |      |
|            |      |
|            |------|
|            |      |
|            |      |
+------+-----+------+
|      |            |
|      |            |
|------|            |
|      |            |
|      |            |
+------+------------+
```

***Mobile***

```
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

I can't seem to get the smaller images to sit on top of each other. The first small image sits right, but the second image wraps onto the next line underneath the bigger image.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*
   FOR ILLUSTRATIVE PURPOSES ONLY.
   NOT PART OF THE OBJECTIVE
*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 650px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 390px;
  margin: 5px;
}

li {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

li:nth-child(2) div,
li:nth-child(3) div,
li:nth-child(4) div,
li:nth-child(5) div {
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/Typhoon101/pen/mvLrYO))

Comment: If all the elements are in one list this is not possible with Flex. as Flex is a one-dimensional layout system. It would seem you need css grid for this.

Comment: Don't over use flex. The layout is possible but you would need to nest for the smaller images and tweak heights so it would fit perfectly. Or as long as your browser support is ok, you can use css grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better consider CSS grid to achieve this layout and you should consider the `ul`/`li` not the div inside as they are not part of the grid.

```css
ul {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr; /*3 columns*/
   grid-gap:5px;
   list-style: none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   max-width:600px;
}

li:first-child {
   background: red;
   height: 300px; 
   grid-column:1/3; /*take 2 columns 1 - 2*/
   grid-row:1/3; /*take 2 rows 1 - 2*/
}
li:last-child {
   background: red;
   height: 300px; 
   grid-column:2/4;
   grid-row:3/5;
}

li {
   border: 1px dotted red;
}

li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(3){
   grid-column:3/4;
   background: green;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row:2;
}

li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(5) {
   grid-column:1/2;
   grid-row:3;
   background: green;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
   grid-row:4;
}

/*remove the grid and use block*/
@media (max-width:400px) {
 ul {
   display:block;
 }
 ul li:nth-child(n) {
   display:block;
   height:200px;
   margin:5px 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is fantastic. Thanks so much.